# Name of property of Laplace transform

Tags: continuous-signals, laplace-transform

\begin{align}
L[e^{-at}u(t)] &= \frac{1}{s+a}\\
L[\cos(\omega_{o}t)u(t)] &= \frac{s}{s^{2}+\omega^{2}_{o}}\\
L[e^{-at}\cos(\omega_{o}t)u(t)] &= \frac{s+a}{(s+a)^{2}+\omega_{o}^2}
\end{align}
Everywhere $e^{-at}$ is multiplied with a function $x(t)$ and the new function becomes $$e^{-at}x(t) = y(t)\ \  {L \atop \leftrightarrow} \ \ \ Y(s) = X(s+a).$$

How is this property called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [Frequency Shifting Property](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/time-scaling-and-frequency-shifting-properties-of-laplace-transform)

Comment: Other names: Time Delay; Pure Delay. It's the simplest manipulation that breaks linearity.